# Use Xpath to select all nodes that extend from base class in xsd

Tags: xpath, xsd

My xsd file is like follows:

```
<xs:complexType name="baseClass">
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="childClass1">
<xs:complexContent>
<xs:extension base="baseClass">
</xs:extension>
</xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="childClass2">
<xs:complexContent>
<xs:extension base="baseClass">
</xs:extension>
</xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

Is there a way to use xpath to select childClass1, childClass2, and all the types that extend from baseClass, without selecting all the childClass individually?

Answer (score 2):

The set of all the complex types declared *in a given schema document* that extend `baseClass` directly can be found with

```
//xs:complexType[xs:complexContent/xs:extension[@base='baseClass']]
```

If you need not only `childClass1` and `childClass2` and so on but also all the types that extend them (and thus extend `baseClass` in one *or more* steps), however, you're going to have to move some of the logic from XPath into some host language and loop over the elements.  What you want to do can be expressed in the following pseudo-code:

1. Start with an empty queue and an empty accumulator.
2. Push `baseClass` onto the queue.
3. If the queue is empty, the set of types you want is in the accumulator.  Stop.
4. (If you reach this step, the queue is not empty.)  Remove the first item from the queue; let `$x` denote its name, if it has one, otherwise let $x be the empty string.
5. Find the set `//xs:complexType[xs:complexContent/xs:extension[@base=$x]]`.  Add them both to the queue and to the accumulator.
6. Go to step 3.

Note that the XPath expressions I have written will find all complex types extending a given named base; if you want only named complex types, change the `//` at the beginning to `/xs:schema/`.